# Google CloudSQL warnings flooding logs

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

For the past few days I get the following two warning entries in my logs every half a second, to the point that the logs (without filtering) are useles.

> CloudSQL warning: your action is needed to update your application and avoid potential disruptions. Please see https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-overview for additional details: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid request: Invalid value for region: . Region name can't be empty., invalid

and

> failed to refresh the ephemeral certificate for ###############: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid request: Invalid value for region: . Region name can't be empty., invalid

The url they point you at is of no use, and there is not region name setting anywhere.

Anyone faced a similar issue?

**This is an appengine standard environment django app and the cloudsql is msql if that helps**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect some recent logging changes on the backend have surfaced these errors. Either way, the log messages point to the problem: you're not including a region when connecting to the Cloud SQL database. Instead you'll want to use something like:

```
/cloudsql/your-project:region:your-db-instance
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but shouldn't this be communicated any other way than log spam? In the url provided there is no explicit mention of the region being required, at least [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-standard)

Comment: @AlexandrosB It's communicated in the codeblock [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-standard#connecting_to) , the codeblock includes the region in the location (at least in python, the rest use the cloud socket we provide from what I'm reading, which is something you set up using the name... which should include the region like enocom says)

Comment: What I'm trying to say in that long comment is that the region is part of the [instance's connection name](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/instance-info#connect_to_this_instance)

Comment: @fabc while technically true, when we set up our project this was not the case. If this is something that will fail in the near future then it should have been better communicated is all I am saying